# Cross-Compiling QT5 for windows on ubuntu host

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, qt5, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile [this wallet](https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonotewallet) on Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I already compiled it for Linux using the docs:

`mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`

But, unfortunately, I don't have a windows machine to compile it.

I tried installing mingw32 and compile using [those toolchains](https://github.com/zyga/cmake-toolchains), and then by using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/656329/723635) but it didn't work and thrown an error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

**PS**: I already installed QT5 using `apt-get install qt5-default`.